# Orthogonal Subspace: $A_p$ and $B_p$ are orthogonally projected by the same projector $P$. Is there always $P$ so that $A_p=QB_p$, where $Q\in O(k)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

Orthogonal Subspace: $A_p$ and $B_p$ are orthogonally projected by the same projector $P$. Existence of $P$ always so that $A_p=QB_p$, where $Q\in O(k)$?

Let $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$ with $A\ne B$ and $n\ge k$. Let the matrices have at least $k$ linearly independent columns i.e. $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=k$.

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an orthogonal projection matrix with a rank of $k$.

The $k\times n$ matrices  $A_p = AP$ and $B_p = BP$ are respectively the projections of $A$ and $B$ onto the row space of $P$. Does the $P$ always exist so that $A_p=QB_p$, where $Q$ is orthogonal?

Comment: *"We know that $A_p$ and $B_p$ are in the same row space."* Do you mean that $A_p$ and $B_p$ are supposed to have identical row spaces?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, $A_p$ and $B_p$ should have identical row spaces since they are both projected onto the row space of $P$.

Comment: $(1,0)\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}=(1,0)$ and $(0,1)\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}=(0,0)$ don't have the same row spaces.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for that. If I relax the requirement to have identical row spaces, will that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the special case where the matrices are square, $B=P=I$ and $A=2B$.